# how to get / set input in array jquery

Tags: jquery, html, arrays, input

I have this array of inputs

```
<select name = device[0][name]>  <select name = device[0][type]>  <select name = device[0][model]> 
<select name = device[1][name]>  <select name = device[1][type]>  <select name = device[1][model]>
```

I would like to set the value of the `device[i][model]` based on the the value of the other two inputs

```
<select name = device[i][name]>  <select name = device[i][type]>
```

the number of array inputs is dynamic so there are `device[0]`, `device[1]` , `device[2]` , .... `device[i]` 
example: if `device[0][name]` value == mobile
and `device[0][type]` value == android
so the values of `device[0][model] are { ICS, marshmallow, KitKat .... }`

and

if `device[1][name]` value == pc
and `device[1][type]` value == desktop
so the values of `device[1][model]` are { IBM, ASUS, HP .... }

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide full html code and the values you are getting from $.ajax().

Comment: I edited the question, is it clear now ?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a .change() event listener then set set the value of the model.

```
$('[name="device[0][name]"], [name="device[0][type]"]').change(function() {
  if ($('[name="device[0][name]"]').val() == 'mobile' && $('[name = "device[0][type]"]') == 'android') {
    $('[name="device[0][model]"]').val('{ ICS, marshmallow, KitKat .... }');
  }
});
```

Comment: this is example data. the number of array inputs is dynamic so there are device[0], device[1] , device[2] , .... device[i]